# curlの証明書チェックができない

Tags: windows, curl, windows-server

■環境
WindowsServer2016
curlバージョン:7.53.1
実行コマンド：`curl -v -x プロキシサーバ サイト名`

上記コマンドを実行した結果、以下のようなエラーとなりました。

```
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013) - 失効サーバーがオフラインのため、失効の関数は失効を確認できませんでした。
```

以下のサイトを参考に「cacert.pem」をダウンロードし「curl.exe」と同じフォルダへ「cacert.pem」をリネームして「curl-ca-bundle.crt」を配置しましたが、エラーが解消されませんでした。対処方法を教えていただけますでしょうか。

[Windows版のcurl.exe で SSL通信のエラーの件](https://tksm.org/wp/archives/3746)

Answer (score 1):

まずcurlは複数のライブラリを扱うことができます。SSL周りもOpenSSLやSchannelを扱うことができます。
参考にされたサイトの記述はOpenSSLを使用した場合の対策なのに対し、エラーはSchannelによるものなので、対策として筋違いなものとなっています。

エラーメッセージは

> 失効サーバーがオフラインのため、失効の関数は失効を確認できませんでした。

で、失効確認つまり revoke に失敗しているため、[オプション `--ssl-no-revoke`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--ssl-no-revoke) を付けることで失効確認を無効化でき、エラーを回避することができます。
（当然ながら失効確認できるべきですが…）

---

参考までにWindows付属のcurlの場合（コマンドプロンプトで実行）

```
C> curl -V
curl 7.83.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.83.1 Schannel
Release-Date: 2022-05-13
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HSTS IPv6 Kerberos Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI UnixSockets
```

Schannelしか組み込まれていません。

git for windows付属のcurlの場合（Git Bash上で実行）

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.82.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.82.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1n (Schannel) zlib/1.2.12 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.2 libidn2/2.3.2 libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.47.0
Release-Date: 2022-03-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI TLS-SRP zstd
$ CURL_SSL_BACKEND=schannel curl -V
curl 7.82.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.82.0 (OpenSSL/1.1.1n) Schannel zlib/1.2.12 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.2 libidn2/2.3.2 libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.47.0
Release-Date: 2022-03-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli HSTS HTTP2 IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI TLS-SRP zstd
```

こちらはOpenSSLとSchannelの両方が組み込まれていて、使用するSSLライブラリは[環境変数`CURL_SSL_BACKEND`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-env.html#CURLSSLBACKEND)で制御できます。重複していて無効化されているライブラリが `()` 表記されるそうです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
別途Curlの再インストールすることでエラーなく実施できるようになりました。